# Installing packages on TeXstudio

Tags: packages, miktex, texstudio, installing

I use TeXstudio on Windows.

I tried to use some symbols from the `wasysym` package and it wrote to me "'wasysym.sty' not found". So I decided to install this package.

The problem is that when I go to MiKTeX Console and go to 'packages', it says

> Sorry, but something went wrong.

and the details of this error are:

> A MiKTeX configuration file could not be loaded.
>
> file="C:\Users\yuraw\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/config\package-manifests.ini", line="219387", error="invalid value definition"`

I have no idea how to fix it.

I know another option of how to install it. I go to the extracted folder of what I have downloaded from CTAN and write in `cmd` `latex wasysym.ins`.
But when I copy the `.sty` file to TeXstudio, it writes errors:

> Font U/wasy/m/n/14.4=wasy10 at 14.4pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
>
> Font U/wasy/b/n/6=wasy6 at 6.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
>
> Font U/wasy/m/n/8=nullfont not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.

And lots of other errors.

Can anybody help me, how to install packages on TeXstudio?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you update recently?

Comment: Unfortunately when I click in miktex console on "check for updates" I see error: `file="C:\Users\yuraw\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/config\package-manifests.ini", line="219387", error="invalid value definition"`, so I don't know why I can't udpate. I installed miktex month ago.

Comment: At this line, I have  `sourceSize=613205`. But maybe it is correct onlyfor my own installation (I have a system wide installation). In MiKTeX console, can you click on the menu `Tasks -> Update package database`?

Comment: in `Tasks -> Update package database` I have `file="C:\Users\yuraw\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/config\package-manifests.ini", line="219387", error="invalid value definition"`. Maybe if you know any outher solution to install package I will be grateful to hear them.

Comment: And what is the value definition at this line?

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out, which program can allow me to go to exactly this line because the .ini file is too big, can you advise some program, please?

Comment: It your TeX editor cannot, Notepad++ can . Mine has 225819 lines!

Comment: Thank you! it is written there at line 219387 `s/cmvtt10o.tfm`

Comment: ?? I have no such line in this file. Maybe the file is corrupted?

Comment: I have no idea, I have never touched this file. what can I do?
Maybe it can help you, the lines from 219385 to 219389 are `run[]=texmf/fonts/tfm/public/zefonts/cmsy10o.tfm
run[]=texmf/fonts/tfm/public/zefo
s/cmvtt10o.tfm
run[]=texmf/fonts/tfm/public/zefonts/zebi1000.tfm
run[]=texmf/fonts/tfm/public/zefonts/zebl1000.tfm`

Comment: It is really magic, but I saw that there are [\newline] between two lines.  So `s/cmvtt10o.tfm` was the part of the previous line! after loading console, my 219387 is `licenseType=lppl1.3`

Comment: Maybe it is enough to fix everything, I will write soon, is it so.

Comment: Yes, everything worked, thank you very much! The problem was that this file was damaged, I deleted unnecessary "newline" command and the packages installed.

Comment: Well– at least you didn't have to reinstall everything! ;o)